# how to rewrite url in .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i want url from this

```
http://localhost/hiraniconfigmgr/subCategoryList.php?category=Test
```

to

```
http://localhost/hiraniconfigmgr/subCategoryList/Test
```

i have try this code, it is working fine, but it block js or css file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((.*)/(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?category=$2
```

even i have used code for hide file extension is working fine code is belowe

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .htaccess is located inside `/hiraniconfigmgr` then you can these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?category=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also keep in mind that you relative links might not work when your current URL is 
`http://localhost/hiraniconfigmgr/subCategoryList/Test`. To fix that you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/hiraniconfigmgr/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Turning off `MultiViews` option using `Options -MultiViews` is recommended since your link name `subCategoryList` is same as `.php` file name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to rewrite `*.php` files.

You could change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((.*)/(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*\.php.*)$ $1.php?category=$2
```

Additionally, if you only want to rewrite paths with `category?=.*` query string parms:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ((.*)/(.*))
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*\.php\?category=.*)$ $1.php?category=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably lookig for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?hiraniconfigmgr/subCategoryList/([^/+])$ /hiraniconfigmgr/subCategoryList.php?category=$1 [END]
```

The above rule will work in the http servers host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess`) located in the hosts `DocumentRoot` without any modification.

An alternative is to place such dynamic configuration file inside the `/hiraniconfigmgr` folder, then the code can be shortened to that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subCategoryList/([^/+])$ subCategoryList.php?category=$1 [END]
```

If you receive a http status 500 when using this rule (internal server error), then chances are that you are using a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag and try again.

If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file (as opposed to the real http servers host configuration), then you have to take care that the interpretation of such files is enabled at all in the host configuration.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).